# Google Now notifications

Tags: android, google-now

Is it possible to get the content like flight info, scores, nearby places from the cards of google now in another app?

For example you have a card for the weather. Is there a way I can get that information like degrees, city and so on?

Comment: I found a Weather API is opend for free.
http://openweathermap.com/
You can get the result as Json String so you need to parse into data you are gonna use.

Comment: Ok thanks but there are several things in gn like scores, flight info, nearby places. Is there a way to get that?

Comment: may be [google Map API](https://developers.google.com/places/). will give you the info. you need to use several apis together I think.

Comment: So you mean if I get all the APIs together I will get a google now like app?

Comment: google now app is using personal data to provide these information you need. Unfortunately there is no google now api in google, and it is impossible to get information from another app in the mobile because Android protect internal information.
 So if you want to make a google now like app, you should get personal information, locations and use various apis to provide the information you want.

Comment: Wow great description! Thank you very much!